# I'm wondering how to add the @synthesize statements for the MovieEditorViewController header file in XCode

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode, properties, terminate, statements

The implementation file looks like this:

```
#import "MovieViewController.h"
#import "Movie.h"
#import "MovieEditorViewController.h"

@implementation MovieViewController

@synthesize titleLabel;
@synthesize boxOfficeGrossLabel;
@synthesize summaryLabel;
@synthesize movie;
```

but i'm thinking my problem is not adding @synthesize statements for the MovieEditorViewController header file. If it's not this then I've included the debugging log below.

I'm really new to programming and I really can't seem to figure out whats going wrong. When I run the iOS simulator and click the button to display editable text fields the program terminates and goes back to the homescreen. The debugger shows as follows:

> [Session started at 2011-06-04
>   13:00:00 +0100.] 2011-06-04
>   13:00:05.568 Movie[6678:207]
>   -[MovieViewController editingViewController]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x8a3bd10
>   2011-06-04 13:00:05.572
>   Movie[6678:207] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[MovieViewController
>   editingViewController]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x8a3bd10'
>   *** Call stack at first throw: (  0   CoreFoundation
>   0x00dc95a9 **exceptionPreprocess + 185
>     1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x00f1d313 objc_exception_throw + 44
>     2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00dcb0bb -[NSObject(NSObject)
>   doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187  3
>
>   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00d3a966 __*forwarding*** + 966     4
>   CoreFoundation
>   0x00d3a522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
>     5   Movie
>   0x000021b4 -[MovieViewController edit]
>   + 62  6   UIKit                               0x002b94fd -[UIApplication
>   sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119   7
>   UIKit
>   0x00349799 -[UIControl
>   sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67     8
>   UIKit
>   0x0034bc2b -[UIControl(Internal)
>   _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527   9   UIKit
>   0x0034a7d8 -[UIControl
>   touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458    10 
>   UIKit
>   0x002ddded -[UIWindow
>   _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567  11  UIKit
>   0x002bec37 -[UIApplication sendEvent:]
>   + 447     12  UIKit                               0x002c3f2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent +
>   7576  13  GraphicsServices
>   0x01721992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
>     14  CoreFoundation
>   0x00daa944
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION**
>   + 52  15  CoreFoundation                      0x00d0acf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
>     16  CoreFoundation
>   0x00d07f83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979   17 
>   CoreFoundation
>   0x00d07840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
>     18  CoreFoundation
>   0x00d07761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97    19
>   GraphicsServices
>   0x017201c4 GSEventRunModal + 217  20 
>   GraphicsServices
>   0x01720289 GSEventRun + 115   21  UIKit
>   0x002c7c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
>     22  Movie
>   0x00001b40 main + 102     23  Movie
>   0x00001ad1 start + 53     24  ???
>   0x00000001 0x0 + 1 ) terminate called
>   after throwing an instance of
>   'NSException'

If anyone could point me in the right direction i'd be very grateful...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're in the [*iPhone SDK Development*](http://pragprog.com/titles/amiphd/iphone-sdk-development) book. Have you made it to section 4.8 yet?  The error says that your `MovieViewController` doesn't have a property named `editingViewController`, which is something you add in 4.8. The project won't build and run until you get through section 4.9, which is where you make some connections.